# Having problems with styling website. Images move when using smaller browser-window

Tags: html, css

As the title says, and as my screenshots show, my images and text move whenever I browse the website using a smaller browser-window. I have tried to search around the web for similar problems but found nothing really helpful.

```
.top-container {
  background-color: #51555c;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 340px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}

.sun {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  top: 80px;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 650px;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
}

.paper-plane {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  bottom: 400px;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[Pictures of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy8zn.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: However as a clue, don't use hard-coded px values when positioning your images...use percentages.